# I want to retrieve data from a Firestore collection group using Flutter, but I'm encountering an error and unable to retrieve it

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In the Flutter app, I'm trying to retrieve data stored in a Firestore subcollection using this method.

```dart
 Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>> fetchNearbyData({
    required LatLng location,
  }) {
    final collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collectionGroup(`postData`);
    return GeoFlutterFire()
        .collection(collectionRef: collectionReference)
        .within(
          center: GeoFlutterFire().point(
            latitude: location.latitude,
            longitude: location.longitude,
          ),
          radius: 10,
          field: `location`,
        );
  }
```

However, an error like this is being generated, and I cannot retrieve the data.

```
W/Firestore( 4280): (24.8.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query( collectionGroup=postData order by location.geohash, __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
I/flutter ( 4280): ----------------FIREBASE CRASHLYTICS----------------
I/flutter ( 4280): [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
I/flutter ( 4280): #0      EventChannelExtension.receiveGuardedBroadcastStream
exception.dart:67
I/flutter ( 4280): #1      MethodChannelQuery.snapshots.<anonymous closure>
```

I believe there might be an issue with the Firestore 'Rules,' and they are set as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /user/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if true;
      match /{path=**}/postData/{postDataId} {
        allow read, write: if true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I retrieve data from the collection group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) reads from all collections with a specific name across the entire database, you need to grant the user permission to all collections of that name across the entire database. But the rules in your question only grant permission to the `postData` collections that are under `user` documents, which isn't good enough.

Move the permission for `/{path=**}/postData/` to be a sibling match for the `user` path:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /user/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
    match /{path=**}/postData/{postDataId} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
So, does this mean that subcollections cannot be considered as collection groups?

Comment: A collection group query reads from all collections with a specific name across the entire database. So it'll read a top-level collection with that name as well as any subcollections with that name.

Comment: I see. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

add this rule

```
    rules_version = '2';service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /user/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if true;
      match /{path=**}/postData/{postDataId} {
        allow read: if true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.
 However, that method doesn't solve the issue.